# Rust Scan function detailed usage explanation

Tags: rust

This a code solution for the problem Delete and Earn, however, I fail to grasp the scan loop part.

The problem states the following.

```
You are given an integer array nums.You want to maximize the number of points you get by  
 performing the following operation any number of times:  

Pick any nums[i] and delete it to earn nums[i] points. Afterwards, 
you must delete every element equal to nums[i] - 1 and every element equal to nums[i] + 1.
Return the maximum number of points you can earn by applying the above operation some number of times.
```

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
impl Solution {
    pub fn delete_and_earn(mut nums: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        let (min, max, counts) =
            nums.into_iter()
                .fold((0, 0, HashMap::new()), |(min, max, mut counts), n| {
                    *counts.entry(n).or_insert(0) += 1;
                    (min.min(n), max.max(n), counts)
        });;
        (min..=max)
            .filter_map(|n| counts.get(&n).map(|count| (n, count)))
            .scan((0, 0, 0), |(a, b, m),(n, count)| {
                let prev_max = *a.max(b);
                *a = if *m == n - 1 { *b } else { prev_max } + n * count;
                *b = prev_max;
                *m = n;

                Some(*a.max(b))
            })
            .last()
            .expect("invariant violation")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how the code logically achieves the solution? OR are you asking what `.scan()` does? Does the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) not help?

Comment: The code I understand the documentation, but I am confused at what the code does